# SELECT Distinct table items from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out total count of clientIds that are distinct in my table

here are the queries

```
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT count(clientId) as totalrecords FROM quotes WHERE storeEmail = '". $store['email']. "'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $totalRecords = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

            echo 'Total Users Found with Request Quote : ' . $totalRecords . "<br /><br />"; 
            echo 'Press Send button to send notifications to all users <br /><br />'; 

            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT clientId FROM quotes WHERE storeEmail = '". $store['email']. "'";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();                                
    $clients = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

The first query gives me sum of 147 whereas the second query gives me 60

What is wrong with first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`COUNT DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) is what you're looking for:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT clientId) FROM quotes WHERE storeEmail = '". $store['email']. "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT count(clientId)` will return you count of clientId , whether you use DISTINCT OR not.

But the second query will return the distinct clietIds.

And you should to use

`SELECT count(DISTINCT clientId)`

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

The DISTINCT got to go into the COUNT.
If you use prepared statements, you should use parameterized queries like:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT count(DISTINCT clientId) as totalrecords FROM quotes WHERE storeEmail = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($store['email']));

$totalRecords = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

echo 'Total Users Found with Request Quote : ' . $totalRecords . "<br /><br />"; 
echo 'Press Send button to send notifications to all users <br /><br />'; 

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT clientId FROM quotes WHERE storeEmail = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($store['email']));                                
$clients = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```